# "findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode" using react-datepicker with React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, deprecated, react-hook-form, react-datepicker, android-strictmode

I'm having an issue when trying to use "showMonthDropdown" or "showYearDropdown" options with react-datepicker.

Everything is working great until I click on the years or month Dropdown in the date picker, then I get this error in the console ...

[image]

Here's my code ...

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

import { MetadataObj } from "../../types/globalTypes";
import Div from "./InputDatePickerStyles";

type Iprops = {
  control: any;
  name: string;
  label: string;
  errors: MetadataObj;
  minDate?: Date;
  maxDate?: Date;
  showMonthDropdown?: boolean;
  showYearDropdown?: boolean;
};

const InputDatePicker = ({
  control,
  name,
  label,
  errors,
  minDate,
  maxDate,
  showMonthDropdown = false,
  showYearDropdown = false,
}: Iprops) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      {errors[name] && <span className="error">{errors[name].message}</span>}

      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field, fieldState, formState }) => {
          return (
            <DatePicker
              className={errors[name] && "invalid"}
              placeholderText="Select date"
              onBlur={field.onBlur}
              onChange={date => field.onChange(date)}
              selected={field.value}
              dateFormat="d MMMM yyyy"
              maxDate={maxDate && maxDate}
              showMonthDropdown={showMonthDropdown}
              showYearDropdown={showYearDropdown}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputDatePicker;
```

Answer (score 2):

`React-datepicker` relies on the `react-onclickoutside` library which currently has this issue unchecked (i.e. https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside/issues/369).

For my projects, I just let it be for now. At some point, either `react-datepicker` or `react-onclickoutside` will fix it, even more so if this deprecation warning becomes an error.

There seems to be no way to partially disable StrictMode either, although someone on https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16362 (the thread about partially disabling StrictMode) suggests overriding `console.error` to filter out the messages you don't want to see, which could or could not be what you're ready to do.

Comment: So, is "React-Select" a dependency in "react-datepicker"? since I'm using "react-datepicker" here and not "react-select".

Comment: @Ruby thank you for noticing that. I have fixed my answer, it's react-datepicker indeed, not react-select.